# update my Facebook status with the android Facebook API (Version 3.0+)

Tags: java, android, facebook, status

I have been up all night trying to figure out a way to **update my Facebook status with the android facebook API (Version 3.0+).**  I see a lot of posts about this but there all old and use facebook API's 2.0 or less and are now depreciated.  I just need a simple example about a simple request and execute (from what I understand that is what you have to do I just can never get it to work.  I am not sure if I have to give permissions first or what.

This is what I have tried (does not work):

```
public void facebook()
{

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        public void call(
            final Session session,
            SessionState state,
            Exception exception)
        {
            if (session.isOpened())
            {

                Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                    session,
                    "yolo!",
                    new Request.Callback() {

                        public void onCompleted(Response response)
                        {
                                 response.getRequest().executeAsync().execute(null);
                        }

                    });
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Yes you have to give permissions for sure, what's the error log you are getting ?

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020771/android-facebook-sdk-3-0-simple-status-update-without-explicit-login) it may help you

Comment: Did that solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void updateMyStatus(){

    Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this,true,new StatusCallback(){
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception){

            if (session.isOpened()){

                Request.executeStatusUpdateRequestAsync(
                        session,
                        "Hello Social Networking Site",
                        new Request.Callback() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Status updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
}
```